# Ansible: Admin box Multiple Users with SSH Authenication

Tags: ansible

I could use some guidance.
I have an Admin Box with Ansible insalled and need to create users on multiple systems, with SSH Authentication.

I create my SSH Key's,  add the keys to an Ansible Playbook,  when I execute the playbook, it creates the Users on both the Admin Box and Remote Server, and copies the key to the remote Server.

- This can only be done, under root, with SSH Authentication turned on

Below, shows the user "Ansible" was created, and the user was created on both the Admin Box and Remote Server.  It also copied the key.  However, I am unable to authenticate in, with SSH Authentication.

**AdminBox:  CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)** - 
10.6.16.235

```
[ansible@SELC01 ~]$ ls /etc/ansible/pub_key/
ansible  ansible.pub
[ansible@SELC01 ~]$ cat /etc/ansible/pub_key/ansible.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EA.....Qys0/V ansible@localhost
[ansible@SELC01 ~]$
[ansible@SELC01 ~]$ cat /home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EA.....Qys0/V ansible@localhost
[ansible@SELC01 ~]$
[ansible@SELC01 ~]$ groups
ansible root wheel

[ansible@SELC01 ~]$ cat /home/ansible/.ssh/known_hosts...
10.6.16.106 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNh.....
```

**Server:  CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)** - 10.6.16.106

```
[ansible@SELC02 ~]$ cat /home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EA......Qys0/V ansible@localhost
[ansible@SELC02 ~]$
[ansible@SELC02 ~]$ groups
ansible root wheel
```

**Admin Box:  CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)** - 10.6.16.235

```
[ansible@SELC01 ~]$ ssh ansible@10.6.16.106
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
[ansible@SELC01 ~]$
```

Not sure why I am getting access denied. So, user Ansible will be the provisioning user; creating accounts, so other users can login to the Admin Box to perform maintenance on other systems, e.g. 10.6.16.106

thank you for your help.

Comment: Your question could be improved with some formatting. You also need to specify which OS is used.

Comment: Sorry was in a hurry, I updated the original question

Comment: Why do you think `ssh` command will use a private key saved in `/etc/ansible/pub_key/ansible`? (*Is it the private key at all? Why is it saved in a directory named `pub_key`? Only to make things more obscure for ServerFault users?*) It seems like you have no idea how SSH public key authentication works. You should read some tutorial first.

Comment: You must have missed my very first comment "I could use some guidance",
As I mentioned "root" works for SSH authentication.  As far as "...you have no idea..."  I do have some idea.  again, root works.   I've just never created more than one key for system before, for additional users. 
As in this playbook  https://github.com/msergiy87/ansible-create-users
they create pub files in /pub_keys. 
The user requirement is for the Provisioning Admin "ansible" to create the keys, accounts, groups for each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ssh` client doesn't know anything about your generated keys. You need to put them into `~/.ssh` sub-directory or create `~/.ssh/config` to point to your SSH keys:

```
Host 10.6.16.106
  IdentityFile /etc/ansible/pub_key/ansible
```